# Interpretation of Lagrange Multiplier as Shadow Price

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Consider the following problem:
\begin{align}
&\min_{(x, y)} (c_x \cdot x + c_y \cdot y)\\
\text{s.t.} \quad & K = x + y\\
&(x, y) \in[0, X] \times [0, \infty)\\
& c_x < c_y \\
& X \geq 0\\
& K \geq 0
\end{align}

The solution is trivial: $(x, y) = (K, 0)$ if $X \geq K$ and $(x, y) = (X, K - X)$ if $X < K$.

I'd like to solve the problem via the Lagrangian approach.
Let $\mathcal L(x, y, \lambda) = c_x \cdot x + c_y \cdot y + \lambda \cdot(K - x - y)$ denote the Lagrangian. The FOCs read
\begin{align}
&\frac{\partial L}{\partial x} = c_x - \lambda = 0\\
&\frac{\partial L}{\partial y} = c_y - \lambda = 0\\
&\frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda} = K - x - y = 0
\end{align}
Obviously, there is a contradiction as $c_x = \lambda = c_y$ and $c_x < c_y$ cannot be true at the same time.

I'd rather think the FOCs read:

**Case I:** For $K \in [0, X)$
\begin{align}
&\frac{\partial L}{\partial x} = c_x - \lambda = 0 \Longrightarrow x = K\\
&\frac{\partial L}{\partial y} = c_y - \lambda > 0 \Longrightarrow y = 0\\
&\frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda} = K - x - y = 0
\end{align}

**Case II:** For $K \geq X$
\begin{align}
&\frac{\partial L}{\partial x} = c_x - \lambda < 0  \Longrightarrow x = X\\
&\frac{\partial L}{\partial y} = c_y - \lambda = 0 \Longrightarrow y = K - X\\
&\frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda} = K - x - y = 0
\end{align}

And the interpretation of the Lagrange multiplier in the sense of a shadow price would be: if $x$ can serve $K$ and there is an extra demand of one unit of $K$, then the price to serve this extra unit would be $c_x$, else $c_y$.

- What is the proper reasoning for the FOCs and the correct derivation of $\lambda$? I came to the conclsuion only because I knew the correct solution beforehand, which must not be the case in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget the multipliers for the *inequality* constraints too:
$$\mathcal{L}(x,y,\lambda, \mu) = c_x x + c_y y + \lambda(K - x - y) - \mu_1 (X - x) - \mu_2 x - \mu_3 y$$
Stationarity of the Lagrangian is no longer sufficient on its own; we need to add the complementarity conditions to arrive at the "Karush-Kuhn-Tucker" [(KKT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions) conditions for first-order optimality:
$$\nabla_{x} \mathcal{L} = c_x - \lambda + \mu_1 - \mu_2 = 0$$
$$\nabla_{y} \mathcal{L} = c_y - \lambda - \mu_3 = 0$$
$$K - x - y = 0$$
$$0 \le \mu_1 \perp (X - x) \ge 0$$
$$0  \le \mu_2 \perp x \ge 0$$
$$0 \le \mu_3 \perp y \ge 0$$

These last three conditions are "complementary slackness";
the "perp" symbol $\perp$ indicates that at most one of the values can be nonzero
(e.g. if $\mu_2 > 0$, then $x = 0$, or if $x > 0$, then $\mu_2 = 0$).

We have a system of nonsmooth equations that must be solved for the values of $(x, y, \lambda, \mu)$. In general, this is hard. For this problem, though, it helps us understand your two cases (slightly modified):

**Case 1**: $K \in (0,X)$

We expect the solution to be $(x,y) = (K, 0)$. We always have $X - x > 0$ and $x > 0$, which means $\mu_1 = 0$ and $\mu_2 = 0$ by complementary slackness. Further, since $y$ is zero, $\mu_3$ is allowed to be nonzero. The stationarity of the Lagrangian becomes $c_x - \lambda = 0$ and $c_y - \lambda - \mu_3 = 0$, which gives $\lambda = c_x$ and $\mu_3 = c_y - c_x$.

**Case 2**: $K > X$:

We expect the solution to be $(x,y) = (X, K - X)$. We have $X - x = 0$, $x > 0$, and $y > 0$, which, again by complementary slackness, implies $\mu_1$ may be nonzero, $\mu_2 = 0$, and $\mu_3 = 0$. Using this in the other equations we get $c_x - \lambda + \mu_1 = 0$, and $c_y - \lambda = 0$. Similarly, we get $\lambda = c_y$, and $\mu_1 = c_y - c_x$.

In general, the value of $\lambda$ is what you were expecting. A little more precisely, the value of $\lambda$ is the derivative of the optimal objective value as a function of $K$:
$$ f(K) = \min_{x,y} \{c_x x + c_y y : -x - y = -K, x \in [0,X], y \ge 0\} $$
$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial K} = \lambda $$

Note I have left out the "breakpoint" $K = X$ in the cases above since this is a point where multiple values of the multipliers $(\lambda, \mu)$ are possible. This corresponds to a point where $f$ has a non-singleton-valued generalized gradient.

Caveats: KKT conditions are only necessary and sufficient for optimality for  problems satisfying certain conditions. A decent resource for diving deeper is [https://stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf](https://stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf) (plus many other books).

Comment: Thanks. I'm wondering, however, that e.g. for the first case we show $\lambda = c_x$, and then you say in general $\partial (c_x \cdot K + c_y \cdot 0) / \partial K = c_x = -\lambda$. This does not fit together, does it?

Comment: Yes, good catch. Equality constraints are the same if we multiple both sides by $-1$; the sign of the optimal value of $\lambda$ depends on this. I will edit the answer to be more consistent with the original sign convention.

Comment: Ok. But then again, for the first case e.g. $\mu_3 > 0$, as $y=0$ and we also have $\mu_3=c_x - c_y <0$. There seems to be an issue with sign consistency.

Comment: Yeah, good point. I guess I should have refreshed my memory on some of this. Edited the answer to match up. The mnemonic is that you add "penalty terms" to the Lagrangian. An inequality constraint $g(x) \le 0$ should be paired with a nonnegative multiplier so it contributes a positive value to the Lagrangian when it is violated.